# I need help making a script to pull http video Links from a m3u into files that are .strm with the same name as the Video file

Tags: bash

I have this Script for creating m3u files for my IPTV Service....

```
    #M3U Grab
    cd ~/xtevedock/files/
    wget "http://go.great.IPTV/get.php?username=***********@gmail.com&password=**********&type=m3u_plus&output=mpegts" -O iptv_download.m3u
    for i in "Sports" "News" "Movies" "General Streams" "Documentaries" "Kids" "Regional Locals" "Mini Series" "Music" "NCAAF" "NETFLIX  (series)" "NFL" "RADIO" "VOD - Action" "VOD - Animation" "VOD -  BOX SET" "VOD - Comedy" "VOD - Drama + Crime" "VOD - Family" "VOD - Horror" "VOD - KIDS TV" "VOD - Fantasy - SciFi" "Star Trek TNG (series)" "VOD - Superheroes" "VOD - Western"
    do
    <iptv_download.m3u grep --no-group-separator -A1 'group-title="'"$i"\" >"$i.m3u"
    sed -i '1i #EXTM3U' "$i.m3u"
    done
```

What I would like to do is take the m3u created above and make .strm files out of some of them (.mkv files) for playing in Emby as Regular Video files do. Here is a example of the m3u that contains some of the files...

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="Stargate SG-1 S01 E01" tvg-logo="http://go.teamexpat.ninja:80/images/gvUNea586UfEeMyXbzgI02HzEJT_small.jpg" group-title="StarGate SG1",Stargate SG-1 S01 E01
http://go.teamexpat.ninja:80/series/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/70028.mkv
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-ID="" tvg-name="Stargate SG-1 S01 E02" tvg-logo="http://go.teamexpat.ninja:80/images/53I9owrjVTMuGP103HnuyjqwRvA_small.jpg" group-title="StarGate SG1",Stargate SG-1 S01 E02
http://go.teamexpat.ninja:80/series/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/70033.mkv
```

To be loaded in the Emby Library, they would need to contain the http Link, and be called Stargate SG-1 Sxx Exx, and Emby would automatically load them as Individual Streams. I can do this manually, but my service has a lot of these stream files and it would be huge task. I have very little knowledge writing scripts, so please don't state the obvious :). I am more than willing to research how to take a variable (i) and be able to add the changing Series info on the end and also strip all other data except the link and rename the file Stargate SG-1 Sxx Exx.strm, but i don't know where to begin.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a resolution to this. A Programmer Developed a Program called [Xtream Downloader](http://iptv-tools.com/tutorial-convert-to-strm.php) that does this, 10 Euros

I would still like to see a simple Bash Script to do this but this solves the issue! If anyone wants help setting this up, See me on [Discord](https://discord.gg/DpZhbEy).

Comment: Please explain the downvote? This is not my Program I am Advertising, just a resolution to my Problem. I am not affiliated to that software in any way. Just trying to help others......